# Get records from Json file in MS EntityFrameworkCore using asp.net core

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, asp.net-web-api

There is a JSON file on the desktop.

I want this API to grab that file and then read all the records within that file so it is ready to display and available for requests.

Right now it is importing everything from the JSON file into an object but I cannot go any further.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TodoController : Controller
{
    
    private readonly TodoContext _context;
    public TodoController(TodoContext context)
    {

        _context = context;
        if (_context.TodoItems.Count() == 0)
        {
            string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Prog\A.json");
            object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(allText);

            int x = jsonObject.
            _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItems { Id = '1', Name = "Item1", IsComplete = false,  });
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written the code in constructor, its not a good approach to write in that way. Probably what you can do is add GET/POST method depending on your requirement. I have made a GET api call to execute your case.Please check below code snippet.

```
            [Produces("application/json")]
            [Route("api/TodoController")]
            public class TodoControllerController : Controller
            {
                private readonly TodoContext _context

                public void Get()
                {
                    _context = context;
                    if (_context.TodoItems.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Prog\A.json");
                        object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(allText);

                        int x = jsonObject.
                        _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItems { Id = '1', Name = "Item1", IsComplete = false, });
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/ToDo")]
public class ToDoController : Controller
{
    private TodoContext _context;
    public TodoController(TodoContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Upload")]
    public HttpResponseMessage UploadData()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_context.TodoItems.Count() == 0)
            {
                string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Prog\A.json");
                object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(allText);

                int x = jsonObject.
                _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItems { Id = '1', Name = "Item1", IsComplete = false, });
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever a service call comes for the controller. On that time It will invoke the constructor. Instead of this, if we move the code to a separate method and invoke this method when required. It will increase the performance and also remove any calls to invoke the constructor unwantedly.

Comment: What should I do with this?

Comment: You can use this method, While request comes for fetching all the records. 

If the record count is zero, then insert record then returns the collection, otherwise returns the collection. 

Instead of post method you can modified as get request.